# Java: Order a list of Objects based on Calendar date?

Tags: java, list, sorting, calendar

I have a list of `Java` Objects that all contain the following field:

```
@JsonProperty
@Column(name = "date")
private Calendar date;
```

I want to order the list of objects based on the above field , the object with `date` field *most recent* first.

What is the best way to do so?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead depending on your exact requirements use `LocalDate`, `ZonedDateTime` or some other class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Comparator.comparing`, suppose you have `List<Entity>` then you can do this way

```
objList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Entity::getDate).reversed());
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort by date ascending

```
yourList.sort(Comparator.comparing(YourObject::getDate));
```

Sort by date descending

```
yourList.sort(Comparator.comparing(YourObject::getDate).reversed());
```

Comment: Thanks, does my object need to implement the comparable interface

Comment: @java12399900 No your Object does not need to implement comparable, as you are sorting by the field date of type `Calendar` and Calendar already implements comparable.